# What's the best way to create a string of childIDs for each parentID in SQL, while excluding the current childID from the aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

**Data**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cats;

CREATE TABLE cats
(
    litterID int NOT NULL,
    catID int NOT null,  --row uniquifier
    catFirst varchar(30),
    catLast varchar(30),
    catSize int
);

INSERT INTO cats (litterID,catID,catFirst,catLast,catSize)
VALUES
('20020314','20262607','Scat','Meow','8'),
('20020314','20264036','Paws','Furbs','4'),
('20020314','20264267','Alexander','Meow','2');
```

**Problem**

For each catID create a string of *their littermates* (this is the hard part ...removing them from the set of members)

**Expected Output**

```
catID     catFirst     litterID  littermates
--------  ---------    --------  -----------------------------------------------
20262607  Scat         20020314  "Paws Furbs Size 4; Alexander Meow Size 2"
20264036  Paws         20020314  "Scat Meow Size 8; Alexander Meow Size 2"
20264267  Alexander    20020314  "Scat Meow Size 8; Paws Furbs Size 4"
```

I've tried EXCEPT query, CURSOR, WHILE.  I think the solution lay in CROSS APPLY.

Comment: I am not sure why this is closed as unclear, whereas you provided the basic pieces of information that the community usually expect: input data (as runnable SQL), and output as table text. That said... you can use `cross apply`, as in: https://dbfiddle.uk/THq6F-G3.

Comment: God bless you and your work!  Thank you.  This is the answer.  Why is cross apply so nebulous to me? I'll get there.

Comment: It "applies" the resultset of its inner query to every row of the outer query. `OUTER APPLY` functions like a left-join, `CROSS` like an inner-join

Comment: I'm not sure why it was auto-closed either; I attribute it to arrogant artificial intel... hopefully this question rises above a (-1) because I was warned by the AI bot it would be.
Important to note this solution is for MSSQL 2017 or greater because STRING_AGG. Earlier versions of SQL will have to use troublesome XML hack approach instead, which can choke on funky characters in the cat's name. (For example, D'Andre Meow"

Answer (score 2):

You want to list all other cats that belong to the same litter on each row.

One option uses a correlated subquery, or `apply`:

```
select c.*, c1.*
from cats c
cross apply (
    select 
        string_agg(concat_ws(' ', c1.catFirst, c1.catLast, 'Size', c1.catSize), '; ')
            within group(order by c1.catID) littermates
    from cats c1
    where c1.litterID = c.litterID and c1.catID <> c.catID
) c1
```

For each row in the outer query, what `apply` does is re-open the same table, then look for rows that have the same `litterID` and a different `catID` - then `string_agg()` aggregates the names and size into a scalar value.

| litterID | catID | catFirst | catLast | catSize | littermates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20020314 | 20262607 | Scat | Meow | 8 | Paws Furbs Size 4; Alexander Meow Size 2 |
| 20020314 | 20264036 | Paws | Furbs | 4 | Scat Meow Size 8; Alexander Meow Size 2 |
| 20020314 | 20264267 | Alexander | Meow | 2 | Scat Meow Size 8; Paws Furbs Size 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/THq6F-G3)